# JDBC: Create Table with PreparedStatement, SQL Syntax Error or not?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am encountering some difficulties trying to, in a dynamic way, create a new table using PreparedStatement. I am trying to add a unknown number of columns and their respective types and sizes. I keep getting SQL Syntax errors, but I suspect this may not be the case here.

Variables used:

- **con** = Connection object
- **colNames** = String[] containing column names ("person", "email" etc)
- **colTypes** = String[] containing column types ("varchar", "int" etc)
- **colSizes** = String[] containing column sizes ("100", "11", etc)

Should be pretty self-explanatory.

```
con.setAutoCommit(false);
String sql = "? ?(?),";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.addBatch("create table " + tablename + "( ");

for (int i = 0; i < colNames.length; i++){

    if (!(i == colNames.length-1)) {
        ps.setString(1, colNames[i]);
        ps.setString(2, colTypes[i]);
        ps.setString(3, colSizes[i]);

    } else {
        String format = "%s %s(%s)";
        String lastLine = String.format(format, colNames[i], colTypes[i], colSizes[i]);
        ps.addBatch(lastLine);

    }
}

ps.addBatch(");");
ps.executeBatch();
```

NOTE: Yes, this is homework. I don't want any dead giveaways, rather pointers as to in what way I am misusing some functions, which I suspect.

Best regards,
Krys

Comment: depending on your DBMS/JDBC driver you also need to remove the trailing `;` in your SQL string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the full SQL statement to addBatch. It is not a tool to construct a dynamic SQL statement. It is a tool to improve performance when running multiple statements. You don't need it here.

You also don't need a PreparedStatement here, as you are not going to have bind variables (i.e. column data as opposed to column names) and are not going to run the same SQL repeatedly (but it does not hurt, either). `setString` and friends do not work for column or table names, just for data.

A StringBuilder is a good tool to construct a String with variable parts.

Comment: I am running certain parts of the SQL Query multiple times (the "colname coltype(typesize)" part) and others ("create table x (" and ");") only once. Therefore I am unsure which way to go, in this case.

I will look into this StringBuilder, if you believe that is the most appropriate tool for this task.

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot run parts of the query. You are running just one CREATE TABLE statement just once. The whole thing is a single statement, and it must be issued in one piece. You need to construct the String with the complete statement before giving it to the database.

Comment: I thought addBatch() did that.. But I rewrote it with StringBuilder and it works very well. Thank you :)